# How to get Properties of Video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, rubygems

Does anyone know how to get properties of video on Ruby on rails (methods or gem) ?

eg : just like image properties (width, height, dimension.. etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For video analysis I prefer FFMPEG at most. Actually I did not use it in any rails projects but you can find the gem [streamio-ffmpeg gem](https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg), which looks promising.

Comment: Finally I'm using streamio-ffmpeg gem. tkanks to anka. GBU

Answer (score 0):

Be warned, videos have a *lot* of properties and sub-formats.

You can get an XML video description using `mediainfo` binary, and use e.g. `nokogiri` to parse it.

Comment: Finally I'm using streamio-ffmpeg gem. tkanks to anka. GBU

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Paperclip::Geometry.for_file(source)
```

you will get Height, Widht, Orientation